# javascript liste sur plusieurs lignes

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items contained in a dynamically created div. Unfortunately when the list is too long, it overflows the div. Is there a way to get a newline when the list overflows?

CSS:

```
div.StdDiv{
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
    }
ul.boxy {        
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;        
    text-align: center;
    }

ul.boxy li {
    cursor:move;
    display:inline;       
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding:2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divListMots" class="StdDiv">
<span id="ListMots">la la lere</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var numlist = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
var textlist = ['li0','li1','li2','li3','li4','li5','li6','li7','li8','li9'];
var ListMots ='';
var ListOfWordsStart = '<ul class="boxy" id="ul">&#160;&#160; ';
var ListOfWordsEnd = '</ul>';
var LiWordStart = '<li id="box' ;
var LiWordEnd = ' " class="">' ;
var LiWord ='';
var sep = '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;';
var Output = '';

for (var k=0; k<numlist.length; k++) // pour tous les trous
{   
var num = numlist[k];
var WordText = textlist[num];
LiWord = LiWordStart + num +  LiWordEnd + WordText +'</li>' + sep;
Output = Output + LiWord ;
}
ListOfWords = ListOfWordsStart + Output + ListOfWordsEnd;
document.getElementById('ListMots').innerHTML = ListOfWords;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z2Zc/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asked in French

Comment: Actually, not technically off-topic. Stack Overflow guidelines are silent on language. I think it's unlikely to get answered as is though, since this is a vastly English-speaking site.

Comment: Please read [Is English required on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)  (tl;dr: yes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question in english:

> Hello,
>
> I have a list of items contained in a dynamically created div.
>   Unfortunately when the list is too long, it overflows the div. Is there
>   a way to get a newline when the list overflows?

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of

```
display: inline;
```

New CSS:

```
ul.boxy li {
    cursor:move;
    display:inline-block;       
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding:2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyPVw/)

You should note, however, that this may not work with older browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry for not using the dominant language ...